# Using pagination and slice to jump x rows in a table until the length of the table rows

Tags: html, angular, typescript

maybe someone could help me figure this one out.

I want to create pagination for my table. It looks like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let cus of customers | slice (0:10)" >
```

Let's say that my table has over 50 rows.

And I want to use slice to in order to jump from (0:10) then (10:20), (20:30) until customers.length which in this case is 50.

I have a pagination navbar:
[image]

and a function in my ts. that gives me the index of the page I'm clicked.

```
clickPage(page: IPaginator) {    
this.clickedIndex = page.pageIndex;
```

}

So basically if I click 1 (0 is returned, 2 ( 1 is returned) etc.

How do I define the "slice" to see 10 rows at a time?

Like

```
slice ( clickedIndex * 10 :  ???? customers.length ???)
```

Comment: `| slice (clickedIndex*10):(clickedIndex*10+10)`

Comment: Thanks that works great! Only problem is, it feels like I need to determine the length of the list too somehow so the pagination list is limited. Like if I get 49 rows in a search.

Comment: Never mind it worked great! Thanks again!